# Text is not getting entered in the edit text control

Tags: android

When I am trying to create tab control and add an edit text in Android, and then enter any character from UI (within Tab1 for Edit Text), the text is not getting entered in the edit text control. I am using Android Studio 1.1.0. Code is as follows.

Main Activity.class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAB_1_TAG = "one";
    private static final String TAB_2_TAG = "two";
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_tabs);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1_TAG).setIndicator("Tab1"), FirstContainerFragment.class, b);

        b.putString("key", "One"); 

        b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("key", "Two");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2_TAG).setIndicator("Tab2"), SecondContainerFragment.class, b);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        boolean isPopFragment = false;
        String currentTabTag = mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
        if (currentTabTag.equals(TAB_1_TAG)) {
            isPopFragment = ((BaseContainerFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAB_1_TAG)).popFragment();
        } else if (currentTabTag.equals(TAB_2_TAG)) {
                isPopFragment = ((BaseContainerFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAB_2_TAG)).popFragment();
        }
        if (!isPopFragment) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

my_tab.xml

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

BaseContainerFragment.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class BaseContainerFragment extends Fragment {

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    public boolean popFragment() {
        boolean isPop = false;
        if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            isPop = true;
            getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        return isPop;
    }

}
```

container_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_framelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

FirstContainerFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FirstContainerFragment extends BaseContainerFragment {
    private boolean mIsViewInited;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fragment, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (!mIsViewInited) {
            mIsViewInited = true;
            initView();
        }
    }
    private void initView() {
        replaceFragment(new FirstFragment(), false);
    }
}
```

FirstFragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText edtTxt;
    TextView txtView;
    Button btnEnter;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.first_layout,null);
        edtTxt =(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        txtView =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textText222);
        btnEnter = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            txtView.setText(edtTxt.getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

similarly I have the following class and layouts

SecondContainerFragment.java
SecondFragment.java

Comment: Try `txtView.setText(edtTxt.getText().toString());` instead.

Comment: Actually I am not able to enter any characters into the edit text control from keyboard

Comment: Still having trouble? So, you are not able to "click" on it to enter text (you don't get a keyboard or anything)? If not, what happens when you "click" on it? Does it crash or do you get a logcat message? Where is the `first_layout` XML?

Comment: Yes you got it right. No it does not crash niether any message comes just the cursor focus does not come to edit text.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
 <TextView android:text=" Name :"
        android:id="@+id/textText222"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

Comment: <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textText222"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

Comment: <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
Above is my  first_layout XML